# Nambu-Goto action using ADM metric

Tags: string-theory, metric-tensor, variational-principle

I start from the Nambu-Goto action:$$ 
S=-\frac{T_{0}}{c} \int_{\tau_{i}}^{\tau_{f}} d \tau \int_{0}^{\sigma_{1}} d \sigma \sqrt{\left(\dot{X} \cdot X^{\prime}\right)^{2}-(\dot{X})^{2}\left(X^{\prime}\right)^{2}}
 $$

I then get the Lagrangian density:
$$ 
\mathcal{L}\left(\dot{X}^{\mu}, X^{\mu \prime}\right)=-\frac{T_{0}}{c} \sqrt{\left(\dot{X} \cdot X^{\prime}\right)^{2}-(\dot{X})^{2}\left(X^{\prime}\right)^{2}}
 $$

I calculate $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{X}^{\mu}}$ and $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial X^{\mu \prime}}$

$$ 
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{X}^{\mu}}=-\frac{T_{0}}{c} \frac{\left(\dot{X} \cdot X^{\prime}\right) X_{\mu}^{\prime}-\left(X^{\prime}\right)^{2} \dot{X}_{\mu}}{\sqrt{\left(\dot{X} \cdot X^{\prime}\right)^{2}-(\dot{X})^{2}\left(X^{\prime}\right)^{2}}}
 $$

$$ 
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial X^{\mu \prime}}=-\frac{T_{0}}{c} \frac{\left(\dot{X} \cdot X^{\prime}\right) \dot{X}_{\mu}-(\dot{X})^{2} X_{\mu}^{\prime}}{\sqrt{\left(\dot{X} \cdot X^{\prime}\right)^{2}-(\dot{X})^{2}\left(X^{\prime}\right)^{2}}}
 $$

Now we use the scalar product definition:
$$ 
\boldsymbol{u} \cdot \boldsymbol{v} :=\boldsymbol{g}(\boldsymbol{u}, \boldsymbol{v})=g_{\mu \nu} u^{\mu} \boldsymbol{v}^{\nu}
 $$

So that $$ 
\dot{X} \cdot X^{\prime}=g_{\mu \nu}\dot{X}^{\mu} X^{\nu\prime}
 $$

So If I want to use the ADM metric for $g_{\mu \nu}$, which I found to be:$$ 
g_{\alpha \beta}=\left( \begin{array}{cc}{g_{00}} & {g_{0 j}} \\ {g_{i 0}} & {g_{i j}}\end{array}\right)=\left( \begin{array}{cc}{-N^{2}+\beta_{k} \beta^{k}} & {\beta_{j}} \\ {\beta_{i}} & {\gamma_{i j}}\end{array}\right)
 $$

Do I just put it in an multiply above or is there something more to it?

Comment: Why do you want to bring the target space metric on ADM form?

Comment: To see how the action changes in curved space time and then derive the equations of motion and use different boundary conditions.